# Как правильно писать: прилагаю копии документов или копию документов?

Tags: окончания

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: "прилагаю копиИ документов" или "прилагаю копиЮ документов"? Например: прилагаем три разных документа. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот интересный вопрос, кстати. Обычно пишут "копию", но это, вероятно, неправильно.

Comment: А если так: я же прилагаю копию одного документа, копию второго документа, копию третьего и т.д. Экземпляр копии - один, значит копиЮ?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, "копи**и**", если документов больше одного и копировались они по отдельности. Единственный альтернативный случай - если технически скопированные документы представлены на общем листе (напр. при копировании одновременно укладывались в планшет сканера или ксерокса).